# angular 6 dynamic form generator with material design

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, dynamic-forms, ondemand

Can anyone help me to create this dynamic form with  data loaded from an http call(on demand ) ?
the working example of code without on demand data is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gaztsv

and i tried myself to load the data on a button click but that is not working, please find it below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gaztsv-1azc56?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fdynamic-form%2Fdynamic-form.component.ts

and the document which i referred is this
https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you created a method to load your fields, but your not calling it so the  form is not being loaded.
For that you need to do this:
On you app.component.ts you need

```
implements OnInit
```

and you need to load your method on the

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.loadvalues()
}
```

Like this when the component is loaded angular will populate your form!
If you want this with a button do like this:
get a boolean variable for example on your app.component.ts you can make this: `visible: boolean = false;` 
and then `loadvalues(){ this.visible = true; }` 
and in the form this: `<dynamic-form [fields]="regConfig" (submit)="submit($event)" *ngIf="visible"> </dynamic-form>`

If you whant to show and hide in the same button do like this:

```
loadvalues(){
    if(this.visible)
    {
      this.visible = false;
    }else{
     this.visible = true;

    }
}
```

Also you need to load the fields on the top.

```
 regConfig: FieldConfig[] = [
   {
      type: "input",
      label: "Username",
      inputType: "text",
      name: "name",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Name Required"
        },
        {
          name: "pattern",
          validator: Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
          message: "Accept only text"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "input",
      label: "Email Address",
      inputType: "email",
      name: "email",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Email Required"
        },
        {
          name: "pattern",
          validator: Validators.pattern(
            "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$"
          ),
          message: "Invalid email"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "input",
      label: "Password",
      inputType: "password",
      name: "password",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Password Required"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "radiobutton",
      label: "Gender",
      name: "gender",
      options: ["Male", "Female"],
      value: "Male"
    },
    {
      type: "date",
      label: "DOB",
      name: "dob",
      validations: [
        {
          name: "required",
          validator: Validators.required,
          message: "Date of Birth Required"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "select",
      label: "Country",
      name: "country",
      value: "UK",
      options: ["India", "UAE", "UK", "US"]
    },
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      label: "Accept Terms",
      name: "term",
      value: true
    },
    {
      type: "button",
      label: "Save"
    }
  ];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i called it from html on button click, thats how i wanted to load the values, not on ngOnInit(),  please check app.component.html

Comment: Well you can get a boolean variable for example on your app.component.ts you can make this: `visible: boolean = false;` and then `loadvalues(){
   this.visible = true;
}` and in the form this: `<dynamic-form [fields]="regConfig" (submit)="submit($event)" *ngIf="visible">
  </dynamic-form>`

Comment: tried that too still same error, got it fixed using ngchange, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but might help someone struggling with dynamic forms using json
This might help someone
https://github.com/saqibumar/angular-6-dynamic-form-using-material/!